# SQL: Select * where attribute matches all items in array

Tags: sql, arrays, select

Working in a Rails App, I have the following table structure (pertinent columns only)

Photos (id: integer)
Taggings (photo_id: integer, tag_id: integer)
Tags (id: integer, name:string)

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT distinct photos.* 
FROM \"photos\" INNER JOIN \"taggings\" ON \"photos\".\"id\" = \"taggings\".\"photo_id\" 
                INNER JOIN \"tags\"     ON \"tags\".\"id\" = \"taggings\".\"tag_id\" 
WHERE \"tags\".\"name\" IN ('foo', 'bar')
```

When I generate this query I'm passing in an array of tags (in this case `["foo","bar"]`). The query correctly searches for photos that match ANY of the tags passed in the array.

How can I change this query to select records with ALL of the given tags (ie a photo only matches if tagged with "foo" AND "bar", instead of selecting records with ANY of the given tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a better way, but this should do it

```
SELECT photos.id,max(otherColumn)
FROM \"photos\" 
INNER JOIN \"taggings\"
ON \"photos\".\"id\" = \"taggings\".\"photo_id\" 
INNER JOIN \"tags\" 
ON \"tags\".\"id\" = \"taggings\".\"tag_id\" 
WHERE \"tags\".\"name\" IN ('foo', 'bar')
group by photos.id
having count(*) = 2 --2 is the number of items in your array of tags.
```

Comment: This works, but in PostgreSQL I continually run into the classic "PG Error: column ______ must be included in Group By clause or used in aggregate function." I can avoid that by grouping by all the columns, but do you know of a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in rails you don't need query to do this.

`Tags.find(1).taggings` should give you an array of all photos with that tag

```
you can also use Tags.find_by_name("foo").taggings
```

you can similarly iterate over all tags, and collect the arrays and then just do something like on the arrays you have got.

```
[ 1, 1, 3, 5 ] & [ 1, 2, 3 ]   #=> [ 1, 3 ]
```

Basically 'and' the arrays and get the unique photos.This way you can get the photos that match all the tags.

Comment: Not a good idea since it requires multiple database calls and potentially returning a lot of data into memory. Of course it may be fine for a small data set and low number of users.

Comment: No, this won't work. I'm using this to create a search method on Photos that I can chain with other methods. It has to originate with photos so it can be scoped etc.